# Relationship problem between entities

Tags: design, database-design, relationships

I'm not sure how I should think regarding my database design. I have made this database schema below. And I'm trying to think about the relationship between the entities. I have read through online that **many-to-many** should be avoided as much as possible and it makes sense. But in my case here, can it be avoided and how? The idea is that there should exists only "unique" items in the WalletStorage and WalletPlatform table that one or many can be owned by a Wallet.

For example, my reasoning is that a **Wallet** can have many **WalletPlatform** and **WalletStorage** that it owns. Also, a **WalletPlatform** and a **WalletStorage** can not just be part of one **Wallet**. But soon as I implement this in for example Hibernate for a **one-to-many** relationship between **Wallet** and **WalletPlatform** and **WalletStorage** it attaches a column in the **WalletPlatform** and **WalletStorage** for each row with the `wallet_id`. It probably does exactly what it supposed to do, but I'm clearly missunderstanding something here.

In the wallet_storage table the structure is this:

```
id    name     wallet_id
```

In the wallet_platform table:

```
id    name     description    wallet_id
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're simply telling Hibernate to set up a one-to-many relationship backwards from what you intended.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your description here.  "a Wallet can have many WalletPlatform and WalletStorage that it owns." Are you saying a single wallet can be associated with more than one WalletPlatform and WalletStorage?  Is there any relationship between WalletStorage and WalletPlatform?

Comment: Bridge tables are often used to deal with many-to-many situations.  You need to understand what your data base vendor supports for many-to-many and bridge tables.  You need to understand whether whatever will be making the queries to extract information from your data base has the capability of dealing with bridge tables. Some tools have a relatively elegant switch, some require hand-coding of the SQL.

Comment: "I have read through online that many-to-many should be avoided as much as possible and it makes sense."  They should not be avoided when that is the natural relationship!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The schema is inconsistent

There is a discrepancy between the designed diagram and the foreign keys:

- you designed in your diagram a one-to-many relationship for `Wallet` with `WalletPlatform`, `WalletStorage` and `CryptoCurrency` (i.e. one wallet could have several platforms, storage or currencies), but
- the foreign keys added in the schema to the `Wallet` implement a many-to-one in the opposite direction (i.e. a wallet can have only one platform, storage or currency,  but those could be associated with several wallets).

Is it possible that you have a mismatch in the Hibernate definition of the associations/relations? In case of doubt, don't hesitate to update your question with the annotations you've used.

### And a missing many-to-many relationship?

I’m not very knowledgeable of the wallet world, but I am very familiar with currencies. In this respect, I wonder if the relationship between `Wallet` and `CryptoCurrency`, in both the designed diagram and the foreign keys is correct:

- according to your diagram, a `Wallet` can be associated with several `CryptoCurrency` rows,  but each crypto-currency can only be associated to a single wallet.  For example, only one wallet could use bitcoins and all the other wallets have to use something else??
- according to the generated FK, a wallet could be associated to a single currency,  but a currency could be used by several wallets.

I understand that a wallet should be able to hold several crypto-currencies, and a crypto-currency can be held by several wallets.  That's many-to-many.  There is absolutely **no valid reason to avoid many-to-many if this is the reality of the domain**.

Many-to-many implies the use of an [association table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html) (also called junction table, intersect table or bridge table):

- hibernate is perfectly able to generate it (see for example this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49472539/3723423)).
- if you prefer, you can [manually break down](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ids_ddi_186.htm) the many-to-many in your diagram with two one-to-many relations with an intermediate entity (`e.g.CurrencyInWallet`).

***Hint**: The breakdown with an additional entity makes sense if it reveals a well identified domain entity (e.g an “assignment”), and even more if it could have own attributes. But often, this is not the case and the additional entity would seems somewhat artificial; it usually start with the difficulty to find an entity name. In this case, prefer to keep your diagram simple and just use a junction table without promoting it to a full-blown entity*

Comment: Thank you Christophe, everything is clear now.